# Create new parent of JSON objects

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, api

I wonder how to alter an array so that it has a name. I need to call the object from my Flutter frontend app.

In this case, its name is "results".
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTWMU.png)

That's my unamed array:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnKJt.png)

This is my model class:

```
const db = require('../config/db');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserModel = require('./user.model')
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const EventSchema = new Schema({
        "type": "String",
        userId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: UserModel.modelName
        },
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "event name can't be empty"],
            unique: true,
        },
        desc: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, "desc is required"],
        },
        eventDate: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: [true, "eventDate can't be empty"],
        },
        pic: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            required: [true, "pic can't be empty"],
            unique: true,
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            lowercase: true,
            required: [true, "price can't be empty"],
        },
},{timestamps:true});


const EventModel = db.model('event',EventSchema);
module.exports = EventModel;
```

Could you help ?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can create model and access these all properties using index values like

```
class ArrayModel{
List<InnerItem> listItems;
}

    class InnerItem{
String _id;
String nombre;

 }
```

And when you want to use this just get all data

var data = ArrayModels();

var list = data.listItem;

var singleItem = list[0];//1 or 2